# C xamarin JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ERREUR

Tags: xamarin.android, deserialization

I can't make my list, I have an error in my code but I can't find how to solve it. here is my little code,
I am taker of all remaque to make me evolve on my code and my know-how :

```
{
"count" : 14568491,
"first" : "https://hubeau.eaufrance.fr/api/v1/hydrometrie/observations_tr?pretty&code_station=V501401001&grandeur_hydro=H&cursor=&size=2",
"prev" : null,
 "next" : "https://hubeau.eaufrance.fr/api/v1/hydrometrie/observations_tr?pretty&code_station=V501401001&grandeur_hydro=H&cursor=AoJwyNmH//YCPwxWMzUzMDAwMV9WMzUzMDAwMTAxX0hfNF8yMD 
 IxLTAxLTEzVDIzOjQwOjAw&size=2",
    "api_version" : "1.0.1",
 "data" : [ {
"code_site" : "V3524010",
"code_station" : "V352401001",
"grandeur_hydro" : "H",
"date_debut_serie" : "2021-01-13T00:00:01Z",
"date_fin_serie" : "2021-01-13T23:40:00Z",
"statut_serie" : 4,
"code_systeme_alti_serie" : 31,
"date_obs" : "2021-01-13T23:40:00Z",
"resultat_obs" : 1099.0,
"code_methode_obs" : 0,
"libelle_methode_obs" : "Mesure",
"code_qualification_obs" : 16,
"libelle_qualification_obs" : "Non qualifiée",
"continuite_obs_hydro" : true,
"longitude" : 4.786558451,
"latitude" : 45.206032312
 }, {
"code_site" : "V3530001",
"code_station" : "V353000101",
"grandeur_hydro" : "H",
"date_debut_serie" : "2021-01-13T00:00:01Z",
"date_fin_serie" : "2021-01-13T23:40:00Z",
"statut_serie" : 4,
"code_systeme_alti_serie" : 31,
"date_obs" : "2021-01-13T23:40:00Z",
"resultat_obs" : 816.0,
"code_methode_obs" : 0,
"libelle_methode_obs" : "Mesure",
"code_qualification_obs" : 16,
"libelle_qualification_obs" : "Non qualifiée",
"continuite_obs_hydro" : true,
"longitude" : 4.769828561,
"latitude" : 45.191519092
  } ]
 }
```

below the class I use, is this good?

```
    public class Datum
    {
        public string code_site { get; set; }
        public string code_station { get; set; }
        public string grandeur_hydro { get; set; }
        public DateTime date_debut_serie { get; set; }
        public DateTime date_fin_serie { get; set; }
        public int statut_serie { get; set; }
        public int code_systeme_alti_serie { get; set; }
        public DateTime date_obs { get; set; }
        public double resultat_obs { get; set; }
        public int code_methode_obs { get; set; }
        public string libelle_methode_obs { get; set; }
        public int code_qualification_obs { get; set; }
        public string libelle_qualification_obs { get; set; }
        public bool continuite_obs_hydro { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public double latitude { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public string first { get; set; }
        public object prev { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
        public string api_version { get; set; }
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }
```

the code I am using has some errors, I am a beginner in this area of ​​use:

```
 var malist = new List<string>();
                Root json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(resultH);
                
                foreach (var order in json)
                {
                    string vader = order.data.resultat_obs;
                    malist.Add(vader);
                }
```

my goal is to get my list of "resultat_obs". What do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need loop like this:

```
var malist = new List<double>();
Root json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(resultH);

foreach (var order in json.data)
  {
     double vader = order.resultat_obs;
     malist.Add(vader);
  }
```

Comment: yes it is better, thank you. last question, I would like to display my my search in this form:

resultatdateheure.Text = malist; (my result list)

I think you should use : ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: @michael if you want display a list,you could use listview with ArrayAdapter.